# WildFly 10.1 Service is not starting

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10, prunsrv

When starting the WildFly service it fails with the error message:

```
The data area passed to a system call is too small.
```

---

This is how I installed the service:

I have copied `C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\docs\contrib\scripts\service` to `C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\bin\service`.

Similar to how it was working with WildFly 8, I have installed the services with the following command:

```
service install /jbossuser admin /jbosspass mypassword
```

When starting the service using `service start`, the command fails with the following error message:

```
Using the X86-32bit version of prunsrv

The data area passed to a system call is too small.
Failed to start serviceService Wildfly starting...
ERROR: Failed to load service Wildfly configuration
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the quotes around description value:

```
set DESCRIPTION=WildFly Application Server
```

See: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-1719

Answer (score 1):

Delete the value of description in service.bat instead of "Wildfly Application Server"

```
**rem defaults
set SHORTNAME=Wildfly
set DISPLAYNAME=WildFly
rem NO quotes around the description here !
set DESCRIPTION="WildFly Application Server"
set CONTROLLER=localhost:9990
set DC_HOST=master
set IS_DOMAIN=false
set LOGLEVEL=INFO
set LOGPATH=
set JBOSSUSER=
set JBOSSPASS=
set SERVICE_USER=
set SERVICE_PASS=
set STARTUP_MODE=manual
set ISDEBUG=
set CONFIG=
set HOSTCONFIG=host.xml
set BASE=**
```

It worked for me, i think you can use a description without spaces, but i didn't try.

Answer (score 1):

I observed similar error on Wildfly 11.0.0.Final.
But problem was in DISPLAYNAME option. I changed it from default and I had white spaces there and it caused same error.

I changed(Default name is just Wildfly):
set DISPLAYNAME=WildFly Application Server
to:
set DISPLAYNAME="WildFly Application Server"

And it worked. Its weird that quotes in DESCRIPTION cause error and lack of quotes in DISPLAYNAME also causes error(simple name without white spaces don't need quotes).